# Как исправить значения в input Angular?

Tags: angularjs

angularquestion.hol.es

если в таблице в полях Кол-во или Цена увеличить цифру, а потом добавить новую строку, в появившейся строке будут такие же значения что мы только что ввели. И вообще, если в одной строке таблицы изменять значения, они синхронно изменяются во всех строках таблицы.

Как сделать так, чтобы такой синхронизации не было?

Answer (score 2):

У вас каждая строка привязана к одной и той же модели `newItem`. Любое изменение в любой строке будет менять эту модель. Чтобы каждой строке соответствовала своя модель, модели можно держать в массиве, и при добавлении новой строки создавать новую модель и добавлять в массив.

```
$scope.items = [];

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItem = {
      cost: 1,
      qty: 1
    };
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
};
```

А для вывода нужно будет забирать модель из массива по соответствующему индексу строки. У вас там уже есть `ng-repeat`, реализован для массива `choices`. Что-то в таком духе нужно будет сделать и для `items`, я бы возможно даже попробовал их объединить.

Comment: Или добавить абстракции, управляя кадой моделью через новый контроллер, если это оправдано, конечно.